# Angular js pie chart styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, chart.js

How can I style pie chart from [angularjs-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#pie-chart) so it looks like this:

[image]

there are examples on [angularjs-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#pie-chart), this one is good for example:[image]

This one would fit for my needs, I just need to change the color and to make line thiner. Like on the one above.

I did try chart-colors and chart-options. First one is simply not working and I am not sure how to use options.

here is the code:

in controller:

```
app.controller('DashboardController', function DashboardController ($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales"];
    $scope.data = [100];
});
```

In HTML:

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
    chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
</canvas>
```

And this is what I get:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your **`$scope.data`** array should be ...

```
$scope.data = [
   [100]
];
```

To set / change the color of pie / doughnut chart, set **`backgroundColor`** property to an array of color value­*(s)*, in **`$scope.datasetOverride`**

```
$scope.datasetOverride = [{
   backgroundColor: ['#67d2c4']
}];
```

and, to make the line thinner, set **`cutoutPercentage`** property to a number­*(thinness)* in **`$scope.options`**

```
$scope.options = {
   cutoutPercentage: 80
}
```

also, make sure to add the **`chart-dataset-override`** directive in your HTML markup.

**:: working example ::**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['chart.js']);

app.controller("DashboardController", function($scope) {
   $scope.labels = ["Download Sales"];
   $scope.data = [
      [100]
   ];
   $scope.options = {
      cutoutPercentage: 80 //set as you wish
   }
   $scope.datasetOverride = [{
      backgroundColor: ['#67d2c4']
   }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DashboardController">
   <canvas class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"></canvas>
</div>
```